# Knots inside loops

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Reading about practical camping, sailing... knots, you find some of them can be done without having access to the rope's ends (if you don't require it to be attached to another loop, ring, etc.). That is, they can be performed at some point of a closed loop or an endless rope, as you don't need to manipulate its ends (what they refer as to perform the knot [*in a bight* [see section]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bight_(knot))). It seems, with no knowledge of topology, that the criteria to classify knots into this or the opposite categories must be something basic related to parity or some easy to check condition, but I don't manage to find the result, probably due to my lack of topology vocabulary. ¿Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It may sound daft, but in [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory) knots that you can perform on a closed loop without cutting the rope or passing it through itself are considered to be trivial. The problem of recognising trivial knots is called the [unknotting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknotting_problem).

Comment: Any knot that can be tied in a closed loop is, in the way the terms are used in Knot Theory, an unknot. Recognizing the unknot isn't easy (but searching the web for the phrase "recognizing the unknot" should get you some good results).

Comment: Thank you for the terminology. So it is not only basic but  a fundamental and not at all easy question. As read in Wikipedia: The basic problem of knot theory, the recognition problem, is determining the equivalence of two knots. Algorithms exist to solve this problem (...). Nonetheless, these algorithms can be extremely time-consuming, and a major issue in the theory is to understand how hard this problem really is (Hass 1998). The special case of recognizing the unknot, called the unknotting problem, is of particular interest (Hoste 2005).

Comment: Even though knot theory is about knotted loops, you can still model the problem of tying a knot in the middle of an infinitely long rope that you would hook onto something by classifying 2-component links whose components are both unknots.  One of the unknots is thought to be the infinitely long knot by considering one of the points along it to be "at infinity", and the other unknot represents a hook or something that has been closed up.  There is no easy classification.